# Create a cursor in android for a image file that exists in internal memory

Tags: android, sqlite, filesystems, uri

I am trying to create a cursor for a file that exists in internal memory, but I am unable to do so.

```
String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
String filePath= sContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "wallpaper.jpg";

    Cursor mediaExtCur = sContext.getContentResolver().query(mediaUri, projection, MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE + " LIKE ?", new String[] { filePath }, null);
```

but, I am getting  cursor count as 0.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: *MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE* is defined as: `"public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE"` and its value is `0x00000001`, so your `selection` argument passed to `query` method is: `1 LIKE ?`

Comment: @pskink please elaborate your question

Comment: i dont have any question

Comment: @pskink

Cursor mediaExtCur = sContext.getContentResolver().query(mediaUri, projection, MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE + " LIKE ?", new String[] { filePath }, null);

is there anything wrong in the query statement, any better way ?

Comment: add `String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE + " LIKE ?"` and use `Log.d` to see it, it will explain everything

Comment: @pskink , ok, I checked it, the query is wrong, Now I replaced it with 

`Cursor mediaExtCur = sContext.getContentResolver().query(mediaUri, null, MediaColumns.DATA + " IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY ("+MediaColumns.DATA , new String[] { filePath }, null);`

Still, I am getting the same result.

Comment: what do you need `new String[] { filePath }` for if your selection doesnt contain any `?` argument replacement marks ?

Comment: @pskink

I want to create a cursor for a specific `filepath' which I am trying to include in the query.

Comment: do you know what `selectionArgs` are for in `query` method?

Comment: @pskink Not exactly, but i think to "narrow down the search result"